# How do I checkout a file from another commit in Magit

Tags: magit

I've got a file `foo.txt` in branch `A`, and I want to check out `foo.txt` from branch `B` into the index.  On the command line, I would do this:

```
$ git checkout B -- foo.txt
```

I want to be able to do this in magit by going to log, finding the commit I'm interested in (e.g `l o B`),  finding `foo.txt`, and running some command, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: This is now a feature request https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2184.  Thanks for looking at it, maintainers

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As of magit 2.11.0 this is possible directly from the reset dispatcher (`X f` and you may specify the revision and file):

[image]

This can be done programmatically within magit using `magit-file-checkout` which accepts a version spec and the filename (thanks to @Emoses' feature request and @Kyle Meyer's implementation).  Previously the function was named `magit-checkout-file` (from v2.3.0 - v2.9.0).

Comment: `magit-checkout-file` is now obsolete. Use `magit-file-checkout` instead.

Comment: Does this work for an entire directory?

Comment: What if I want to do this with a specific commit hash and file other than the current branch (e.g. master), HEAD or FETCH HEAD?

Comment: @topkek After selecting one of the actions above you select what branch or commit you are resetting to (it doesn't need to be the current branch).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a builtin way to do this.

Assuming you're on branch A, another approach would be to diff branch
B (`d r ..B`), and then move point to the file you're interested in.
Pressing `a` will apply those changes to the working tree (rather than
the index).

I have a command in my configuration to reset or checkout a file from
a revision, but, in its current state, it doesn't fit exactly what
you're asking for because it won't offer a good revision default when
in Magit Revision mode.

```
(defun km/magit-reset-file (rev file &optional checkout)
  "Reset FILE from revision REV.

If prefix argument CHECKOUT is non-nil, checkout FILE from REV
instead.

\(git reset REV -- FILE)
\(git checkout REV -- FILE)"
  (interactive
   (let ((rev (magit-read-branch-or-commit "Revision")))
     (list rev (magit-read-file-from-rev rev "File") current-prefix-arg)))
  (magit-with-toplevel
    (magit-run-git (if checkout "checkout" "reset")
                   rev "--" file)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `evil-collection`, the command is `O` instead of `X` to reset using other branch.

[image]

Comment: Yes I see, it's `evil-collection` config. Sorry for the misleading information. @phils