# Magit equivalent of `git checkout <tree-ish> <path>`

Tags: magit

I would like to reset my working directory to the state in another commit. In pure git, I'd use `git checkout <commit> -- <file>`. Is there a way to reach similar functionality from any of the dispatch popups in magit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I checkout a file from another commit in Magit](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14463/how-do-i-checkout-a-file-from-another-commit-in-magit)

Answer (score 1):

Use `M-x magit-checkout-file RET <rev> RET <file RET`.

Comment: Is there a pre-defined keyboard shortcut for it in one of the dispatch popups?

Comment: No. What is your use-case?

Comment: Well, what is magit's use case? Using Git from emacs without having to type out the git command (or, in this case, an even longer emacs command).

Comment: None. That's why no key is bound to the command. The command exists because someone asked the same question some other time I assume. You can of course bind some key to it. Personally I almost never use it and when then I use the equivalent git command. But if I knew a compelling use then I might be able to think of a suitable key binding. That's why I asked.